# increase button width with screen size

Tags: android, button, layout

I have 3 buttons inside a horizontal layout that fills the whole screen.

```
<LinearLayout   
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="50dp" 
android:text="1" />

<Button 
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="50dp" 
android:text="2"/>

<Button 
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="50dp" 
android:text="3"/>
```

My 2 problems are:

1. How can I make the right button stick to the right edge of the screen without modifying it's width?
2. How can I make button number 2 fill the vacant space between button 1 and 3 without modifying its width?

Comment: 1. You want to stick the right edge of right button without modifying right button's width?  2. You want to make second button fill up the space between the first and last - that would mean width of second button should change.  May be you can add more explanation to make it more clear?

Comment: exactly, the only thing is I am searching for a way to scale button 2 width with screen size so it covers the blank space between button 1 and button 3

Comment: Stef, did you have a try with my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using a Relative layout will be the Best solution something Like this.

```
<RelativeLayout   
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >



  <LinearLayout   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
android:alignParentLeft=”true”>

<Button
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="50dp" 
android:text="1" 
android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button 2
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="50dp" 
android:text="2"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button 3
android:id=”@+id/button3”
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="50dp" 
android:text="3"
android:alignParentRight=”true”/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is the relative layout or the layout_weight (as I posted 3mins ago)?

Answer (score 2):

using layout_weight should do the job, the weight of a view is the proportion of remaining space that the view will fill.

```
<LinearLayout   
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2"/>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: 1) The non-weighted buttons should omit the weight parameter, not set it to zero. 2) The weighted button should have a width of "0dp" for the weights to play nice.

Comment: darn you I wanted to answer this :P   but yea this is the way to do it.  However setting your width to 100dp will make for some tiny buttons on some phones. You might want to just fill_parent on all of them or set them by %

Comment: @Geobits thanks, good to know, would you mind to explain also why should it be 1) and 2)?

Comment: @Rick I wanted too xD

Comment: For 1) With `layout_weight="0"`, you are specifically saying take up 0% of the room. Omitting it allows `layout_width` to work right. For 2) If you have both a `weight` and `width` in the same direction(`height` for vertical layouts), they conflict with each other. The system doesn't always apply it consistently, so it's best to zero out the width.

Answer (score 0):

try with relative layout....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/relative"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bt1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt3"
    android:text="2" />

<Button
     android:id="@+id/bt3"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help you :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:weightSum="0.6"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.2" >

      <Button
          android:layout_width="100dp"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:text="1" />

      </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="2" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="3" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```